How does clustering affect volatility and correlations differently?
In Betting Against Beta - Frazzini & Pedersen (2014, JFE), the authors state that correlations appear to move more slowly than volatilities, which implies that the clustering phenomenon affects correlations much more than volatilities.
It is also for this reason that the authors use a longer rolling window to estimate ex-ante correlations as compared to volatilities:

Main Question: How true is this? Why has there not been extensive studies made on this? Since it is well-known that volatilities have clustering time series dynamics, why are correlations not as well studied.

No one responded so , if you're referring to the clustering and slow-movement  of correlations, I'll just say that I've never heard that ? ( i've heard of it happening in crisis times but not in general )  but I guess it could be true ? but, it also sounds like, if that were truly the case, there would be some possible arbitrrage possibly ? I'm always leary of these time-frames that people use for estimating $\beta$. The timeframe always seems kind of arbitrary to me. Use a different time frame often = get a significantly different estimate of beta. !!!!!!

@markleeds thanks for your comment, I am of the same opinion too. It seems to good to be true that correlations do exhibit the same properties of vol. I will look more into the part that you mentioned about time-frames.

Hi: Yeah, it sounds strange. I think sometimes ( not saying every time), authors make comments to make their analysis sound deep and complex when it's really arbitrary. Anyone who constructs a  method that estimates beta so that it doesn't change every time a new month comes along, would probably publish it.

The bigger the correlation matrix, the more points are required for a decent estimation (non singular). Moreover, why use the same length for all volatilities if one suspects they move with different speeds? Volatility estimation is already hard, correlation a lot harder. I have seen many pragmatic unjustified schemes, and this is just another one.
